# Laravel input feature didn't work and show error 404

Tags: php, database, laravel

**Hello everyone.** i just learn laravel this month, and i get some problem that haven't solved since yesterday.

So i want to make a feature where i input a token and submit it, and the page will redirect to view page. the token will used by the controller to find row of data that match the token and will return the data to view page. i already (seems) succeed made the feature. the value of input is (should be) the token, initialized with {$kodeunik}, but what's confused me is when i input the form with {$id}  the feature works, but if i inputted with {$kodeunik}, it didn't works. (shows 404) any solution? what should i do? Thanks

For info: ({$id} is the primary key and {$kodeunik} is the unique key)

this is the Controller.

```
public function cek()
{
  return view('cek');
}


public function show(Request $request)
  {
    $kodeunik = urlencode($request -> input('kodeunik'));
    $blog = blog::find($kodeunik);

    if (!$blog)
    {
      abort(404);
    }
      return view('tampil', ['blog' => $blog]);

  }
```

This is the Form view

```
<form method="get" action="/">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="kodeunik" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Kode Unik</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
             <input id="kodeunik" type="text" name="kodeunik">
        </div>
   </div>

     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="cek">
     {{csrf_field()}}
     <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="get">
```

this is the Show View

```
@section('content')
<h1>Detail Laporan kau</h1>
<table class="maxw600 no-padding">
<tr><td><b>Status: </b></td><td>{{ $blog -> tag}}</td><br>
<tr><td><b>Nama: </b></td><td>{{ $blog -> nama}}</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Bagian: </b></td><td>{{ $blog -> bagian}}</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Telp/Ext: </b></td><td>{{ $blog -> telp}}</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Email: </b></td><td>{{ $blog ->email}}</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Subjek: </b></td><td>{{ $blog -> title}}</td></tr>
<tr><td><b>Deskripsi: </b></td></tr>
</table>
<p>{{ $blog -> description }}</p>
<p>{{ $blog -> tanggapan }}</p>
 @endsection
```

This is the Route

```
Route::get('/cek', 'UserController@cek'); //this is route for the form view
Route::get('/', 'UserController@show');  //this is route for showing the result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named id. You may define a primaryKey property to override this convention. Likewise, you may define a connection property to override the name of the database connection that should be used when utilizing the model.

In your case, when you pass id it works because laravel know's that its the default primary key in your table. Now when you pass kodeunik, laravel will still find kodeunik in id field of your table.

So here are some solution how to solve this.

**first :** change the primary key of your table by putting this code in your model

```
 protected $primaryKey = 'kodeunik_field';
```

Second : just use where clause to get a result, like this

```
$blog = blog::where('kodeunik_field', $kodeunik)->get()->first();
```

Comment: hey Qonvex620, thanks for you respon. i've tried your advice. and when i input the form it shows "Property [tag] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: .....\resources\views\tampil.blade.php)". do you have another solution? thanks

Comment: what did you try ? the first one or second one ?

Comment: if you try the where clause then you have to use first() method like this one
$blog = blog::where('kodeunik_field', $kodeunik)->get()->first();

Comment: The two solutions are different. When you use the first solution, no more changes to your controller, and if the second one no more changes in your model

Comment: hey it's work. thanks a lot. but, it also make the {$id} not the primary key, and it affect another route that uses /{id}. ex: Route::get('{id}', 'HomeController@show');.so should i change the {id} to {kodeunik} or do you have solution for this? sorry for extra question.

Comment: oops, okay wait ill try one by one. i'll back with the result

Comment: Yes definitely,  depends on what is in your parameter.

Comment: hey, it's fully working. i use the first one. thank you very much.

Comment: thanks, glad to help you. can you make it as accepted answer ?